# time-series analysis using ARIMA model

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I have a time-series dataset with values of water flow at the given timestamps. Now I want to make a model to train these values such that if any abnormal value appears in the data it should trigger an alert saying there is a problem, needs attention. In order to model the data, I have used ARIMA model but the results dont look appropriate. The forecast looks off. The link to the data is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cFHSVpY0XBxsEayl2k1cK4_qWZ4PvDBd

Am I using the correct model based on the data or should I change the model to produce relevant results.

I have tried the acf and pacf test to find the values for p and q with d=1,2. I also tried decomposing the data to check the trend, seasonality and residuals but it produces a colored block for seasonality and I cannot understand what it means. The autocorrelation plot also produces uninterruptible results.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib
decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df1, model= 'additive')
fig = decomposition.plot()

model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(df1, order=(1,0,1))  
fitted = model.fit(disp=-1) 

  # Forecast
fc, se, conf = fitted.forecast(2000, alpha=0.05)  # 95% conf\
print(fitted.summary())
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=test.index)
lower_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 0], index=test.index)
upper_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 1], index=test.index)

# fc_series
fitted.plot_predict(dynamic = False)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df1.loc['1970-07-24 05:00:00':].plot(ax=ax)
fig = df1.plot_predict('1983-02-19 05:00:00', '1986-12-22 05:00:00', dynamic=True, ax=ax,plot_insample=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: this would be much better suited to the cross validation site no?

Comment: @User632716 sorry I didn't get what you mean

Comment: if your question is on model selection, it might be better asked here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ , stack overflow is a programming website, but your question is more stat focused